# Django: markup - set the top heading

Tags: django, markdown, markup, textile, heading

I am choosing between markup languages mentioned on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/markup/ .

But I need one specific thing - set the top heading. By default, there is h1 the first heading. I need to have h2  as the first. Exists any way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. What do you want to do with the first heading?

Comment: I have h1 already on the page. But the content is separated and I don't want to repeat h1 heading and I want to start with h2.

Comment: UPDATE: I am sorry, I had h1 and h2 tags in the question and they are hidden now.

Comment: me too. What do you mean by 'top/first heading'? Those three have heading/header support (click on the links on that page)

Comment: I *think* he wants to change the level of the H tag so that what would normally be an H1 becomes an H2, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using markdown, you explicitly denote the heading levels. For instance

```
# Heading 1
## Heading 2
```

corresponds to

```
<h1>Heading 1</h1>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
```

If you want to start with heading two, just make sure to use ## everywhere you would overwise use #.

If you want to have this done automatically, I suppose you could have a filter like

```
re.sub('#+', lambda m: m.group()+'#', text)
```

to shift all the headings down one level before passing it into markdown.